# Bean Validation Pattern (start with) is failing

Tags: java, bean-validation

I am using a simple bean validation pattern that should validate if a string starts with TX. When i enter a valid string that starts with TX the validation fails. Is there something wrong with my regex?

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^TX", message = "ID must start with TX", flags = Pattern.Flag.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
private String txId;
```

Comment: Your regex matches `^TX` exactly, no more characters are allowed. Didn't you mean `regexp = "^TX.+"`?

Comment: I have tried with ^TX*$ but it did not worked, will try again.

Comment: `^TX*$` matches words that begin with "T", followed by zero or more "X" - which is not what you meant.

Comment: don't forget the dot. ^TX.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use

```
 @Pattern(regexp = "^TX.*$", message = "ID must start with TX", flags =         Pattern.Flag.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
 private String txId;
```

to really validate that string starts with TX and not consists of just TX at the beginning.